# How would you read this php line?

Tags: php, operators

I'm new to PHP and I really like the concept behind it.  Would you be kind enough to explain to me how a line like this would be read?

```
if ($ThisOutput->result == "success")
```

In other words, what does that line above mean?  How can I understand it?

Thanks!

========

Wow! Thank you to all who have answered!  I totally understand this now!  :-)  I wish I could choose all three of you as the accepted answer, but I can only choose one.  Good job ya'll!

Comment: If the `result` property of `$ThisOutput` equals `"success"`, then ...

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php for an explanation of how classes and objects work in PHP.

Comment: Explaining the syntax constructs from a single line excerpt is not going to teach you much. It's vastly irrelevant without context even. Read through the PHP manual or a book rather. For the syntax: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139)

Comment: Thank you for the links.  I'll definitely be up studying this.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php, variables are denoted by a `$` prefix. Therefore, $ThisOutput is a variable.

There are several types of variables. For variables of type [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) (objects) their properties can be accesed with the `->` operator.

Your code is evaluating if the property 'result' for the object $ThisOutput has a value equal to the string "success".

An `if` construct will execute a further command if the argument evaluates to true. So in this case, if `$ThisOutput->result` is "success" something will be executed, and it won't in any other case.

Answer (score 0):

The -> is used to access variable of functions of php objects.

The exact interpretation of the example depends on the type of object represented by $ThisOutput.

If $ThisOutput is a class, then result would be a member variable of the class. So in that case the line would mean "compare the variable named 'result' in the class $ThisOutput with the string 'success'.